# How to add class to li element usign jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```js
var hash = window.location.hash; // got e.g: #tab-cultura
$(".nav-tabs").find(hash).parent().addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
so for that I am trying this Jquery but seems not working:(
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="tab-null"></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-cidadania" data-cat="cidadania" data-toggle="tab">Cidadania</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-cultura" data-cat="cultura" data-toggle="tab">Cultura</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-educacao" data-cat="educacao" data-toggle="tab">Educação</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente" data-cat="bem-estar-ambiente" data-toggle="tab">Bem-estar
            &amp; Ambiente</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-dinheiro" data-cat="dinheiro" data-toggle="tab">Dinheiro</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-ciencias-e-tecnologia" data-cat="ciencia" data-toggle="tab">Ciência
            e Tecnologia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, on page reload I got this string `#tab-cultura`

now I want to add a class called `active` to `li` element which has `a` tag with attribute `href="#tab-cultura"`

Comment: `$(".nav-tabs [href="+hash+"]").parent().addClass("active");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[href=#tab-cultura]`:

```js
var hash = "#tab-cultura";
$(".nav-tabs [href="+hash+"]").parent().addClass("active");
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="tab-null"></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-cidadania" data-cat="cidadania" data-toggle="tab">Cidadania</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-cultura" data-cat="cultura" data-toggle="tab">Cultura</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-educacao" data-cat="educacao" data-toggle="tab">Educação</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente" data-cat="bem-estar-ambiente" data-toggle="tab">Bem-estar
            &amp; Ambiente</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-dinheiro" data-cat="dinheiro" data-toggle="tab">Dinheiro</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-ciencias-e-tecnologia" data-cat="ciencia" data-toggle="tab">Ciência
            e Tecnologia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have this url: `mysite.com/categorias/#tab-educacao/abs` Now it's showing me: `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tab-educacao/abs` do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

by using your way of selectors,

```js
var hash = window.location.hash; // got e.g: #tab-cultura
$(".nav-tabs").find("[href='"+hash+"']").parent().addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
so for that I am trying this Jquery but seems not working:(
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="tab-null"></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-cidadania" data-cat="cidadania" data-toggle="tab">Cidadania</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-cultura" data-cat="cultura" data-toggle="tab">Cultura</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-educacao" data-cat="educacao" data-toggle="tab">Educação</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente" data-cat="bem-estar-ambiente" data-toggle="tab">Bem-estar
            &amp; Ambiente</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-dinheiro" data-cat="dinheiro" data-toggle="tab">Dinheiro</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-ciencias-e-tecnologia" data-cat="ciencia" data-toggle="tab">Ciência
            e Tecnologia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check # query string From URL

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Add active class in targeted li

```
$(".nav-tabs [href="+hash+"]").parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.

Comment: Please try add some explanation to your answer to make it more useful for others

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".nav-tabs [href='#tab-cultura'").parent().addClass('active')
```

Comment: This would add a class `active` to an element with the `id` `tab-cultura`.